# How to make TextFormField enabled by a button?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to make TextFormField enabled by press a button which is not in the same level,how to pass the value from the button?

[image: Here's UI]

```
return Scaffold(
 child:Column(
  children:[
    Container(
     child: Row(
      children[
      Textbutton(),
       .......//otherButtons
       ]
      )
    ),
     DefaultTabController(
      child: Column(
       children[
        TabBar(),
        TabBarView(
         child:Column(
          children[
            TextFormField(),
            .......//otherTextFormFields   
          ]
         )
        )
       ]
      )
     )
  ]
 )
);
```

Comment: You like to setText on textFiled by button click?

Comment: No,I set a IconButton with suffixIcon,when the IconButton(icon open_in_new_rounded) pressed,it will pop a dialog.What I want is before I press the textbutton on the top,the  IconButton won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set text through `TextEditingController`. and to disable user input, use `readOnly:true`. You can test the widget and get the concept how it works.

```dart
class ColorTest extends StatefulWidget {
  ColorTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ColorTest> createState() => _ColorTestState();
}

class _ColorTestState extends State<ColorTest> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  bool readOnly = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              controller.text = "Got the text from button click";
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Text("set text"),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            readOnly: readOnly,
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              readOnly = !readOnly;

              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Text("ReadOnlyMode: $readOnly"),
          ),
        ],
      )

          // materialButto(),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man you solved my problem,I appreciate that. :)